# Lexing sum operator and a signed integer with PLY Python

Tags: python, regex, lexer, ply

How can I build my raw expression to differentiate between a sum operator and a signed integer? I'm using PLY Python.

This,unfortunately, didn't work:

```
t_sum=r'\+'
def t_integer(token):
    r'[-+]?\d+'
```

Comment: Well here's hint(-ish), the plus _sign_ is a unary operator.  The addition is a binary operator.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but still don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

One way to think about this is, rather than trying to distinguish the purpose of `+` on lexing, is to wait until parsing (where we determine meaning). So keep:

```
t_PLUS  = r'\+'
t_MINUS = r'\-'
def t_INTEGER(token):
    r'\d+'
    return int(token)
```

And define a grammar:

```
number -> number PLUS number          #sum, binary operator
number -> number MINUS number
number -> PLUS number                 #signed integer, unary operator
number -> MINUS number                
number -> INTEGER

#By writing each as a parse functions like...
def p_number_ADD(p):
    "number : number PLUS number"
    p[0] = p[1]+p[2]
```

Note: this does allow the following behaviour `+-+2 = +(-(+2)) = -2` *(as seen in Python)*.

Answer (score 0):

If you could detect unary operator by its surroundings (which is true only if your language is simple enough to list all the cases):

```
a ++ b  // binary +, unary +
```

So we say that `++[a-z]` is unary, and `+[a-z]` is binary (and we list `-+`, `*+` etc. for detecting unary as well).

Then another problem pops up: the surrundings will also attached to the token. In the example: it will be `[a]` and `[++b]`, instead of `[a]`, `[+]` and `[+b]`.